# Implementing a delete function on a Binary Search tree in Python

Tags: python, tree, binary-search-tree

I have to implement a few  functions while following guidelines as stated below.  My main concern is the `delete()` function that I thought was right but doesn't seem to be working correctly. I believe I have to make a helper function in my `Node` class, but I can't actually find the meaning (besides the obvious helper part) of a helper function and how to implement it and what purpose it has "behind the scenes" as to be used from the binary search tree class.

Hopefully someone can help me understand what I am missing from this function. Also , I completely understand the theory behind how delete should work in a BST, and I have chosen to find the minimum value of the right if my node has 2 children.

Also, we are assuming that the key already exists in the node, so we don't have to check for it or any duplicates, AND key should be treated as a data value .

**Exercise Guidelines ...**

> Implement the following operations for a Binary Search Tree class starting from the template provided. Use the `Class TreeNode` that is provided. You may implement helper methods that make your code easier to write, read, and understand. Test cases will be provided later but you should write test cases of your own as you develop the methods. You may use iterative or recursive functions in your implementation
>
> You will likely want to add setters and getters for the tree node fields other than the key field. Changing the key of a node is equivalent to removing and inserting it and that is the safer way to do the implementation rather
>   than trying to move the node to reflect the change in the key.
>
> To implement BST use two classes, because you must be able to create and work with a BST that is empty. The class BinarySearchTree has a reference to the class TreeNode that is the root of the BST. The class TreeNode provides many helper functions that make implementation in class BinarySearchTree much easier.

```
   class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, key):
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.key = key
    self.data = None
    def insert(self, key): inserts a node with key into the correct position if 
    not a duplicate.
    def find_successor(self): # returns the node that is the inorder successor 
    of the node
    def find_min(self): # returns min value in the tree
    def find_max(self): # returns max value in the tree
    def inorder_print_tree(self) # print inorder the subtree of self
    def print_levels(self) # inorder traversal prints list of pairs, [key, level 
                             of the node] where root is level 0
    class BinarySearchTree:
    def find (self, key): # returns True if key is in a node of the tree, else 
    False
    def insert(self, newkey):
    def delete(self, key) # deletes the node containing key, assumes such a node 
    exists
    def print_tree(self) # print inorder the entire tree
    def is_empty(self): #returns True if tree is empty, else False
```

Below here is my code ...

```
class BinarySearchTree:

def __init__(self):
    self.root = None

def insert(self, newkey):
    if self.root is None:            # if the root is set to none then
        self.root = TreeNode(newkey)  # the root is the treenode Then use recurrsion ... Root is the CEO
    else:
        self.root.insert(newkey)    #Here we call the insert method on root for the newKey



def find (self, key):
    p = self.root      # current node
    while p is not None and p.key != key : # this checks to make sure that the key is not a duplicate of itself
        if key < p.key:
            p = p.left
        else:
            p = p.right
    if p is None :
        return False
    else:
        return True     # might want to return the node or ???


def delete(self,key):   #deletes the node containing key, assumes such a node exists
    if key < self.root.key:
        self.root.left = delete(self.left,key)
    elif key > self.root.key:
        self.root.right = delete(self.right,key)
    else:
        if self.left is None:
            temp = self.right
            self = None
            return temp
        elif self.right is None:
            temp = self.left
            self = None
            return temp

            temp = find_min(self.right)
            self.key = temp.key
            self.right = delete(self.right,minkey.key)


def print_tree(self):
    if self.root is not None:
       print_tree
       return root.key








def is_empty(self):
    if self.root is None:
        return True
    else:
        return False



class TreeNode:
"""Tree node: left and right child + data which can be any object"""

def __init__(self,key,data=None,left=None,right=None, parent=None):

    self.key = key
    # self.data = None  WE DONT NEED THIS HERE ITS JUST TO SHOW THAT WE CAN USE IT
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.parent = None



def insert(self, key):
    """  Insert new node with key, assumes data not present """
    if self.key != None:
        if key < self.key:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = TreeNode(key)
            else:
               self.left.insert(key)
        elif key > self.key:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = TreeNode(key)
            else:
                self.right.insert(key)
    else:
        self.key = key   #raise error jic

def inorder_print_tree(self):

    """   Print tree content inorder        """

    if self.root is not None:
        self.left.print_tree()

    print(self.key, end=", ")

    if (self.right != None):
        self.right.print_tree()


def find_max(self): # returns min value in tree
    if self.right is not None:
        return self.right.find_max()
    else:
        return self.key

def find_min(self): #returns max value in tree
    #we want to rerun the key for min and max
    if self.left is not None:
        return self.left.find_min()
    else:
        return self.key  #this wouldnt be self.left.key because we cannot go any further self.left.key would obviously be past none

def find_successor(self):
    if self.left is None:
        return self.right.find_min()
    elif self.right is None:
        return self.left.find_max()
    else:
        return self.right.find_min()

def __str__(self):

    return str(self.key)


def print_levels(self):
    pass
```

Comment: It looks like there's an `else:` missing in your `delete` function.